# Google API: Using OAuth to get the user's country

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-plus-signin

I'm trying to retrieve the user's country through Google's API. Using `'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me'`, I'd suspect that the user's country would be returned but it does not. I've looked through the docs and StackOverflow, all the the results are about retrieving the user's location using Google Maps, which I'm not interesting in.

The information is inputted when creating an account at the bottom here:
[image: Google create account screenshot]

Is there any way to get this information from Google? Thanks.